# Apple Setting App Complication

Tags: iphone

When I needed storage I did something under the storage section in settings to undownload the apps I haven’t used in a while and if I want to go back into the app after so many days then I have to redownload it but after so many days it undownloads after I downloaded it. How can I get the to stop since I got a new phone and I dont want this to do this any more? It also shows a cloud next to it every time it undownloads.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 11, go to Settings > iTunes & App Stores > and deselect Offload Unused Apps. You may have to redownload already offloaded apps, but it should stop doing it automatically after you change this setting.